# How can titanium be separated from magnesium by washing?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, separation-techniques

I saw this question in a GCSE past paper:

> After this reaction, there is a mixture of the solids magnesium, titanium and magnesium chloride. Titanium does not react with dilute hydrochloric acid. Suggest a simple method to separate titanium from the mixture.

And in the mark scheme, one of the ways you could get the full 2 marks was with this answer:

> filter the mixture (to remove titanium) / filter off the
> titanium (1)
> wash the titanium (1)"

I was wondering how this would separate the titanium from the magnesium (the other way to get 2 marks was to use $\ce{HCl}$ to react with the magnesium before filtering)?

Comment: The mark scheme for the other explanation makes no mention of HCl - only "washing" the titanium after it's been filtered.  It's an Edexcel paper btw.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If your mixture contains titanium $\ce{Ti}$, magnesium $\ce{Mg}$, and magnesium chloride $\ce{MgCl2}$, you may first get rid of magnesium chloride by washing the mixture with water, which dissolves $\ce{MgCl2}$
alone. Then, you add diluted hydrochloric acid $\ce{HCl}$. The metal magnesium reacts easily with diluted solutions of $\ce{HCl}$ (maybe $0.1$ M), producing gaseous hydrogen $\ce{H2}$ and magnesium chloride which remains in solution. At the end, when no bubbling appears on the metallic powder, the remaining solid contains pure titanium.